# Adjective that means "hard to pronounce" even you know how to pronounce it

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a word to describe a word or a sentence that is hard to pronounce, in a situation that even you know the pronunciation but just can't control your tongue. Tongue-twister is the closest that I have come up with so far, but I wonder if there is an adjective.

I want a word that can fit into the blanks:

The script was so _________ that I had to pause and repeat a lot.

This rap is insanely ________.(a word more specific than "hard"/"difficult")

Comment: In the extreme, you could say it's *unpronounceable*.

Comment: The older question cannot be a duplicate because this question is *not* specifically looking for a noun, and the OP has already ruled out *tongue-twister*.

Comment: If you edit and say you accept a phrase or an idiom, your questions stands a better chance of staying open.

Comment: @JEL: none of the answers there are adjectives.

Comment: @JEL: Oops. Sorry, I completely missed that "break-teeth," "crack-jaw," and "cramp" were adjectives; I thought they were nouns for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

> Yeah, sometimes it’s just impossible **to keep up to** Tech N9ne’s machine gun flow, or Young Thug’s yips and yelps.
>   [MTV.com](http://www.mtv.com/news/2197639/hip-hop-songs-you-cant-recite/)

The Busta Rhymes's song entitled **[Can you Keep Up?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veflCk2rHfA)** is an exemplary rap song which is **unpronounceable** because of its sheer speed.

- **keep up** *vi* (often with **with**) to move fast enough not to be left behind (by):
  *Don't run — I can't keep up with you*
  <sub><sup>[Chambers Universal Learners' Dictionary](https://books.google.it/books?id=AB1f965CUnwC&pg=PA510&dq=%22keep+up+with%22+pace&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhkMPl9OXLAhXHA5oKHcYMC1wQ6AEIPzAH#v=onepage&q=%22keep%20up%20with%22&f=false)</sup></sub>
- **unpronounceable** *adj*
  (of a word or name) too difficult to say.

Comment: would it not be more usual to say "impossible to *keep up  **with*** rather than *keep up **to***?

Comment: @CharlE you're right. Well spotted but those are the exact words used on the MTV website. But the dictionary entry includes the preposition *with*. I might change the source/refence if I can find a better one

Answer (score 1):

***Tongue-twisting*** is used as an adjective corresponding to *tongue-twister*; you can see examples of it further down the page here under the section "References in periodicals archive": http://thefreedictionary.com/tongue-twisting

You can also see some examples if you search on Google Books: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=tongue+twisting

One of the results is *[Six thick thumbs: a tongue-twisting tale](https://books.google.com/books?id=Wot80JWIKi8C&q=tongue%20twisting&dq=tongue%20twisting&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGua2Q9eXLAhVMtYMKHZ8pBSsQ6AEIKDAC),* by Steve Charney and Michael Chesworth, where "Tongue-twisters form a tornado which sweeps over a little town and gives everyone except Tom the ability to recite tongue-twisters easily."